# On Hover Pushing Content

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover over an image I set it to display a border radius, because I have a background image and the fact you can't make a border-radius transparent I removed it which has caused an cool but accidentally effect. When you hover over the image in order to display the radius and the padding added it pushes the rest of the page down.

Is there anyway I can keep the effect on a certain part of the page so it moves text and content boxes down, but stop it from pushing the whole page down. This is my code but to get a real example there is a site link, thanks!

```
.service img#dev:hover{
border: 3px solid #76c2af;
border: 3px solid #76c2af;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
border-radius: 80px;
padding:10px;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 service" style="text-align:center;">
    <img id="dev" src="assets/imgs/dev.png">
    <div class="serviceDescription">
        <h3 class="service-title">Hand Crafted</h3>
        <p class="service-description">
                    All of my projects are hand crafted and utilize the latest in web technology. My work boasts a clean & compliant markup and you are rewarded with unquestionable level of perfection.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Live preview here](http://xronn.co.uk/)

Comment: have you tried removing the padding:10px from your :hover css?

Comment: Hi, Yeah they will reduce it but I still want it to push the content box down just not the rest of the page. I didn't know if there was some overflow or something I could add to stop it pushing content below the portfolio bit down. thanks!

Comment: you shoul put border with transprent color on elment, and just fill with color on hover

Comment: please create demos in a code sharing site like jsfiddle.net, plunker, jsbin etc. Once your link changes the demo is useless to others in future who have similar issues. The other benefit is people can then update your code to help provide solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example

```
.service img{
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; /* for Safari */
  background-clip: padding-box; /* for IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome */
  border-radius: 80px;
  padding:10px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

And rest is ok:)

Comment: Hi, I still wanted it to push the content down but what I will do is make some jQuery so when you hover the image it will move it down instead. Thanks for your help! Do you know which browsers support the "transparent" border

Comment: Note: Internet Explorer 6 (and earlier versions) does not support the property value "transparent". So I think you are safe. I dont really understand second part. What you mean with push down content?